# Cannot loop/iterate through a list of WebElements in Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, for-loop, foreach

I am having an issue looping through a list of WebElements. It works the first iteration through but then fails at the second iteration.

### **Workflow**

Loop 1 Executes properly and creates a list of web elements. I did this because I thought Loop 2 was failing because navigation switching (e.g. clicking on the web element)

Durning Loop 2 execution

1. The `ListofLinks` is populated
2. On the first iteration, it works fine, clicks on the web element and finishes the loop
3. On the 2nd iteration `Item.Text` fails. It looks like that item does not exist.

Any thoughts?

```
    var ListOflinks = new List<IWebElement>();

    //Loop 1
                foreach (var item in driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))
                {
                    if (item.Text != "")
                    {
                        ListOflinks.Add(item);
                    }
                }

// Loop 2
 foreach (var item in ListOflinks)
            {
                if (item.Text != "")   // <<<<---- Fails Here
                {
                    // Clicks on Current Link
                    item.Click();
                }
             }
```

Note: Before the I tried the 2 loop solution. I was expeiencing the same results with. It would work for the first web element then fail on the 2nd iteration.

```
foreach (var item in driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))
            {
                if (item.Text != "")
                {
                    item.Click();
                }
            }
```

Comment: when you click on first link, the page potentially changes or navigates to another page. So you need to return to original state to navigate further.

Comment: what are you trying to test here? item.Text != ""

Comment: It is always a good practice to wait for an element to be visible, clickable first. I suggest you implement wait() to your code, see if this makes any differences.

Answer (score 3):

```
IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
IList<IWebElement> listOflinks = new List<IWebElement>();

foreach (IWebElement link in links)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link.Text))
      listOflinks.Add(link);
}
```

That's will give you the all links **references** after the first click **the DOM will change and you will lose all the elements!**

for getting the elements back you will need to initialize the links again

for your purpose you should use for loop to inspect get the correct index

```
IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
IList<IWebElement> listOflinks = new List<IWebElement>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < links.Count ; i++)
{
   links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link[i].Text))
      links[i].Click();
}
```

**if after the click on the link the page is redirect to other you need to change your logic it would not work!**

Comment: Awesome, That was my suspicion but was struggling with a fix.Thank You Leon!

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because when the first link is clicked and you are navigated to new view, the previously found element does'nt exist on the current view.

If thats the case you can navigate back in your 2nd loop and then click the link.